# SEO effect of http-equiv="REFRESH" for redirect

Tags: seo, redirects

Question [Moving Pages to New URL's - Unable to Use 301 Redirects to Tell Search Engines The Pages Have Moved](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/141230) got me thinking - If there is only access to change the content of a page to affect redirection we can use

```
  <meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0; url=XXXXXXX>
```

Of-course, this does not create a 30x status code, but on the other hand is very old (I remember using it with Netscape) and has a very low barrier as its just HTML.

**How does Google treat http-equiv="REFRESH" to a new URL from a redirection/SEO POV?**

Comment: This might help - https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/301-redirects

Comment: Thanks for that - it pretty much provides the answer - provided the refresh is imediate (ie http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=... it treats it as a permanent redirect.   if you post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Done: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/141240/123893

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This might help:

https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/301-redirects

> #### meta refresh and its HTTP equivalent
>
> If server side redirects aren't possible to implement on your platform, meta refresh redirects may be a viable alternative. Google differentiates between two kinds of meta refresh redirects:
>
> - Instant meta refresh redirect: Triggers as soon as the page is loaded in a browser. Google Search interprets instant meta refresh redirects as permanent redirects.
> - Delayed meta refresh redirect: Triggers only after an arbitrary number of seconds set by the site owner. Google Search interprets delayed meta refresh redirects as temporary redirects.
>
> Place the meta refresh redirect either in the `<head>` element in the HTML or in the HTTP header with server side code.